# Checkbox mobile menu closes on "off-click" and link-click (as intended), but not on icon click (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, menu

**Checkbox mobile menu closes on "off-click" or link-click (as intended), but not on icon click.**

Hello!

I'm just dabbling with JavaScript, but I really want do a mobile menu.

I'm using this cool animation for the icon: https://codepen.io/aaroniker/pen/LXVqxR

I have followed the interactive part using this answer:

[How do I close this checkbox menu after the user clicks on the links or outside of the menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58193096/how-do-i-close-this-checkbox-menu-after-the-user-clicks-on-the-links-or-outside)

**Goal: To close the mobile menu on any click interaction.

Right now: Mobile menu closes on any click interaction, except clicking on the icon itself.**

I think it's because of the "`if( e.target != checkbox )`" part, but I have no clue what to replace with it.

**Code:**

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector( '#mobileCheck' );

checkbox.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
  if( this.checked ) {
    document.getElementById("mobile__menu-contents").classList.add("mobile__menu-open");
    document.addEventListener( 'click', listener );
  } 
});

var listener = function( e ) {
  if( e.target != checkbox ) {
    checkbox.checked = false;
    document.getElementById("mobile__menu-contents").classList.remove("mobile__menu-open");
    document.removeEventListener( 'click', listener );
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches): `if (!e.target.matches('#mobileCheck')) {...}`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, I still get the exact same effect. Closes on any click interaction, except on the icon itself.